# Confused with $x$ and $a$ of Taylor Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given general formula of Taylor Series:

> $$T_{n}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^{n}}$$

Why Taylor Series for $f(x)=\sin{x}$ is always evaluated at $x=0$ (the evalution means $a=0$) so we can get desired $\sin{x}$ value  like $\sin{\pi}?$

Comment: You can take any origin you want as long as the the power series around it converges to the function. People usually expand around 0 as it's the easiest to evaluate. If you want to expand around 1, for example, you need to be able to calculate $sin(1)$ and  $cos(1)$

Comment: Note that 1) the series for the sine converges everywhere, and 2) you can always reduce the argument in range $[0,\pi/4]$. This said, there is no problem to evaluate a Taylor series from $a\ne0$.

Comment: @Nescio If I substituted $a=1$ and $x=1$ (in rad), what $x$ in $T_n(x)$ would be? I'm confused in the writing the formula. Also how about writing the $f(x)$?

Comment: @user247433 $f(x) $ would stay the same, the Taylor polynomial is equal to the function (as long as it converges to it). Yves gave a good answer by showing you the power series of $sin$ at a general $a$.  Notice that (alao as Yves stated)  the power series converges for any $a\in \mathbb{R} $ thus $sin(x) =T_a(x) $ for any $a$ and any $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivatives of increasing order at $a$ are
$$\sin(a),\cos(a),-\sin(a),-\cos(a),\sin(a),\cos(a),-\sin(a),-\cos(a),\cdots$$periodically, and the development is

$$T_a(x)=\sin(a)+\cos(a)(x-a)-\sin(a)\frac{(x-a)^2}2-\cos(a)\frac{(x-a)^3}{3!}\cdots.$$
If you evaluate it at $x=a$, all terms but the first vanish:
$$T_a(a)=\sin(a)+\cos(a)(a-a)-\sin(a)\frac{(a-a)^2}2-\cos(a)\frac{(a-a)^3}{3!}\cdots=\sin(a).$$

Comment: Is this okay if I make "Taylor series for $\sin{\pi}$ evaluated at $x=2$ ($a=2$)? This is just my creation.

Comment: I don't get the question, please rephrase.

Comment: Ok how about $\sin{x}$ evaluated at $a=2$? Is this okay to find like $\sin{1/2\pi}$ or $\sin{\pi}$ with $a=2$?

Comment: The series converges for all $x$ and all $a$. Anyway, large $x-a$ difference results in poor accuracy because of cancellation errors.